# get $_POST keys from filter_input

Tags: php, post, filter

In one application I am building, I have a variable amount of text inputs (fill-in-the-blank questions in an online quiz, with variable amounts of blanks). The question ID needs to be identified in the name, as the blank information also needs to be passed back. I also have some hidden validation inputs (a nonce and formID that are checked against values stored on the server, and if the values are sent via javascript an extra value to flag the system to send JSON back) that are identified with an underscore.

Therefore, to filter the system values and the ID's of questions I need, I'm using regex (which works fine).

Currently I'm getting my values with code similar to the following:

```
function input_filter_post($regexfilter,$escapetype,$options) {
    $keys = array_keys($_POST);
    $return = array();
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if (preg_match($regexfilter,$key)) {
            $return[$key] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,$key,$escapetype,$options);
        }
    }
    return $return
}
```

note that I need to use `$_POST` to find the array keys. However, for my actual application I want to unset `$_POST` to force the use of `filter_input`. Is there some way to retrieve the keys from `$_POST` without using `$_POST`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used a wrapper object around `$_POST` that indirectly used filter_input to grab the information.